# QTMobilityAPI - Installation Error

Tags: qt

I am using the nokia qt sdk for developing apps in MAC10.6. I want to access the map api in my project. I download the zip(qt-mobility-opensource-src-1.1.0-beta2) file and tried to install but I am getting the errors like ...

```
make[4]: *** [../../../build/Debug/qtlandmarks_sqlite_debug/qlandmarkfilehandler_lmx.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [debug-install] Error 2
make[2]: *** [sub-sqlite-install_subtargets-ordered] Error 2
make[1]: *** [sub-landmarks-install_subtargets] Error 2
make: *** [sub-plugins-install_subtargets-ordered] Error 2
```

What I did wrong in the installation. Please help me.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are errors earlier in the build but the output you posted doesn't show them.